# How to configure (Brother) Laser Scanner

Tags: scanner, brother

I am not able to configure the scanner of my Brother DCP-7030.

- After following all the steps mentioned on [Brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html#brscan)
- Also, I implemented the solution provided in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340908)

When I try to scan the documents, the printer shows the display "Connecting to PC", but does not scan the document. I am however able to print the documents.

Any solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have correctly installed the drivers?

- Open a terminal and run this `sudo lsusb`
- Where your printer / scanner is (My scanner/printer was listed as 002/004)

  ```
  sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/002/004
  ```

Comment: The ouput for sudo lsusb is Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd Am having 004 file (not folder)located under /dev/bus/usb. How do i execute the sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb in this case.

Comment: Correction - the 004 file is located under /dev/bus/usb/001

Comment: [Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub]

[Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet]
[Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd]

Comment: Unfortunately the Block format cannot be done, in this text field. I have provided the single line results of lsudb output in  []. Hope it helps.

Comment: Am not aware of "<S>" tool, but in my next 3 post, I would be pasting the output of each row output of lsusb command. Hope it helps.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet

Comment: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd

Comment: Apparently the printer is located here: Bus 001 Device 003 -  so this is how to change the permissions **sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/003**

Comment: Still not able to scan the documents :(

Comment: are you using `XSane` - `simplescan` do you have the libraries installed

Comment: have you looked here http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-7030

Comment: XSane-Simplescan - Both don't detect the scanner. Yes, installed the drivers listed in Brother website and followed the instructions.

Comment: Any clue why the scanner is not getting detected?

Comment: Out of Ideas here. Will do some other searching if i find something I will post it

Comment: thanks mate for the assistance. I have tried all possible solutions. fyi..am using Virtual Box

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2785/discussion-between-viraj-rao-and-bluexrider)

Comment: @VirajRao Please PLEASE make sure you edit your post with new details instead of posting them in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for scanning with my DCP-1510-series scanner. I checked if the driver was properly installed and it was OK. I thought it was a permission problem, but nothing changed after trying every single permission workarounds.

So

1. I installed *XSane*
2. Headed to scan image properties window, changed the color value to *Black & White* and voila!