# DCP-1510 driver problem for scanner

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

The [DCP-1510](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1510_eu_as) came with a driver CD for Mac OS and windows but not ubuntu(linux). I recently switched from Windows to linux and [was able to download a driver from the brother's page.](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1510_eu_as) . I did as the instructions were given AND the printer seems to work, but scanning doesn't work. The error message says "USB can't connect" in the PC and "Can't connect to PC" in the scanner's LCD display. What should I do?

I would have contacted their support but their form keeps popping error messages and I can't even register, but I seriously need to use the scanner.

Comment: Brother offer an install script: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1510_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625&dlang=true and that should install the scanner correctly for you;

Comment: ......... if you stick to manual editing, see this http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on#u13.04 .......... and here http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on which is the fAQ: ....... sadly you need to check through each of the 3 ubuntu entries to see if they apply eg `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4` and then copying files; as you have brscan4 then `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/sane

Comment: `then `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so /usr/lib/sane`then `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1 /usr/lib/sane`

Comment: @pdc, i did use the install script, and that is how my printer worked but scanner failed to work. My pc doesn't detect scanner when the usb is connected

Comment: @pdc, Using __sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4__ command told me that the newest was installed

Comment: @pdc, and nothing about using the machine with the ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: @pdc, It was already installed, so I just copied the files, as you had mentioned above, but, still no result, it says cannot scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same problem and found the answer here : [How to configure (Brother) Laser Scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112448/how-to-configure-brother-laser-scanner)

it's a permission problem